# Regaining trombone embouchure after 3 years off

Tags: trombone

I am looking for advice. After 3 years I would like to return to playing trombone (I stopped- due to braces). Now I can't form my embouchure correctly (no vibrations) :(

Do you have some recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

If there are truly no vibrations, remember that what creates the vibrations is the airsteam. As such, it might be best for you to begin with some breathing exercises to get back in the habit of the deep breaths and high volume of air that's necessary to play the trombone. (If it's been three years since you played, I wouldn't be surprised if you got by doing these breathing exercises.)

I would then recommend going back to the horn. When you put the mouthpiece to your face, exhaling like you practiced in your breathing exercises should create some vibration (and thus a sound). At that point, use that initial pitch as your starting point. Move outward in range from that pitch, and let your sound guide you towards improving your embouchure.

If, however, you'd rather not jump right to the instrument, you can also try doing the above using just the mouthpiece. But in my experience, it will be easier at this stage to get a sound using the instrument than without using it.

You could also consider getting a mouthpiece rim to help you really solidify your embouchure:

[image]

Mouthpiece rims are especially common for trombone players, since the Denis Wick line of mouthpieces include the interchangeable mouthpiece parts (including the rims).

Answer (score 0):

Your embouchure will return quite soon. You’ll need some more time. (After a break of 25 years I started to play euphonium again.) Close your lips and press the air down in your lungs. Start buzzing. Put a pen by the end in your lips and let it hang down just holding it with your lips to strengthen your muscles.
There are many useful videos with tutorials giving advices how to improve the embouchure.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311552654_Fundamentals_of_Embouchure_in_Brass_Players_Towards_a_Definition_and_Clinical_Assessment

https://www.brucepearsonmusic.com/articles/TeachingTheBrassEmbouchure.pdf